# Open UI5 basic setup

Tags: html, user-interface, sapui5

i am using Eclipse Keepler where i have install Open UI5 plugins. I am able to create a project as SAPUI5 Application Development , i have a index.html page in it by default which has a following line

```
<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
```

here i am getting warning "Undefined attribute name Role" moreover by default in my index.html i have got below generated code under Script Tag.

```
    <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
    </script>
```

**where is this sap-ui-core.js file present** ? 
**and why i am not able to automatically get sap.ui.core library and sap.ui.localResource class in the Script tag** ?
I have followed SAP Developers guide but its not helpful. Please help me out as I have just started with OPEN UI5 some link with basic information on it will be helpful.

below is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>


  <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
  </script>

  <script>
        var myView = new sap.ui.jsview("sampleopenui5/Main");
        myView.placeAt("content");
</script>


</head>
 <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

below is the error message i am getting

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
http://localhost:8758/sapui5/resources/sap-ui-core.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running on Tomcat, the resources "folder" is actually set up as a servlet unpacked from a jar file. If you look in the WEB-INF/web.xml file you'll see this:

```
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- UI5 resource servlet used to handle application resources      -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->

<servlet>
    <display-name>ResourceServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ResourceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sap.ui5.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ResourceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Your Tomcat server should show the jar deployed in your Servers tab:

[image: Servers tab showing resources jar]

If you set up the UI5 library for any web server, you'd just have copied the resources folder out of the [openui5 sdk distribution](http://openui5.org/download.html) and put it in your project.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Undefined attribute name Role' indicates your DOCTYPE is incorrect. It should be `html`

If you run your application on the local eclipse web server, there should be no problem finding the resources. So how do you run your application?

Comment: i am using Tomcat-7.0 to run the application.

Comment: Ok, so I assume you have deployed the UI5 libs to your webserver, right? Is the path correct? Can you access the UI5 help files from your tomcat server?

Comment: No i didn't, how to do that could you please help me out, I have just downloaded the plugins into my Eclipse Keepler for UI5 and started working. Please guide me.

Comment: Just downloading the plugins will of course not magically have your Tomcat web server be aware your eclipse plugins See http://help.sap.de/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/d5/6826f550d74e02b8d4b32cb264de52/content.htm for configuration. But you could (for testing purposes) also use the online, absolute URL in your bootstrapper instead of the relative URL: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js

Comment: Thank you very much :) . But still i have a doubt can you please guide me where this resource folder is pointing at which contains sap-ui-core.js ?

Comment: As it is a relative path, it should be on your web server, relative to where your application is running. For instance, if your app runs at `http://localhost:8010/mycontext/someapp/index.html`, according to your index.html file the bootstrap file should then be located at `http://localhost:8010/mycontext/someapp/resources`

Comment: My errors are gone but still "Undefined attribute name Role" warning is there in index.html . And thanks for the help.

Comment: Like I said, your DOCTYPE is incorrect, probably still pointing to HTML 4.01 or so, instead of html5 content. See solution in my answer

Comment: Where can i see the bootstrap file i.e. resource/sap-ui-core.js ? i want to see the physical copy of it. I am very much confused with it.