# Where do you put the libraries(sap.ui.core.js etc.) when downloading OPENUI5 SDK locally

Tags: eclipse, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 Application developed via Eclipse(Using SAPUI5 Plugins) and now i want to call it to deploy on a Web Server.

But, in eclipse, i downloaded the plugins and libraries through Eclipse->New Software. Now, i want to download all libraries from http://openui5.org/download.html and place it locally.

Now, in eclipse version the code was

```
<script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js">
```

Now that i have downloaded the OPENUI5 SDK, where should i put it and how to refer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you will use Tomcat as a web server for testing, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846186/open-ui5-basic-setup) the basic steps for installation.